# Почему не работает тернарное условие?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{data && data.dataFromLocal ? data.dataFromLocal.map((item,idx) => {
            return <CartItem {...props} IDX={idx} Name={item.title} key={idx} Price={item.price} ImgSrc={item.images[0].image} Id={item.id}/>
          }) : <p>Hello world!</p>}
```

Я ожидаю что когда массив пустой он будет показывать `Hello world`. Но он этого не делает

Comment: Какой массив вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko **data.dataFromLocal**

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов лучше сказать где и что вам не нравиться. Изложите свою мысль конкретно и скажите что я сделал не так. Так мне будет понятнее и постараюсь не допускать таких ошибок

Comment: `data && data.dataFromLocal` - так вы проверяете, что `data.dataFromLocal` - это не `falsy` значение. Но не проверяете на заполненность массива элементами. Для этого есть свойство `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {data && data.dataFromLocal.length ? (
        data.dataFromLocal.map((item, idx) => {
          return (
            <CartItem
              {...props}
              IDX={idx}
              Name={item.title}
              key={idx}
              Price={item.price}
              ImgSrc={item.images[0].image}
              Id={item.id}
            />
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <p>Hello world!</p>
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data && data.dataFromLocal` - так вы проверяете, что data.dataFromLocal - это не falsy значение. Но не проверяете на заполненность массива элементами. Для этого есть свойство length. **Stepan Kasyanenko**